# Is there some program to speak on the micropohone and get the recognized text along with a translation to other language

Tags: speech-recognition, translation, speech-synthesis

I'm looking for a sowftware where I can speak to the microphone and get the recorgnized text and also a suggested translation in a different format.

The objective is to help people have written online conversations in languages that are not their own.

I saw many speech-to-text projects and also translating apps, but none that seems to combine them for this particular purpose.

The ideal thing would be something like google translate, but instead (or in addition to) writing the text I could just speak to the microphone (or perhaps a different app to do that)

> Thanks to an answer, I found out that I was missing the mic icon in Google translate, I switched to google chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you see the microphone icon in Google Translator? I can easily speak my texts in both desktop and mobile after clicking that icon.

You could also use a browser add-on like "Speech recognation anywhere" (Chrome) and then also use translation tools without speech recognition like deepl.

In addition, most keyboards on smartphones and tablets would also have a voice input function. You might also want to clarify your question and tell on which devices or operating systems it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find the mic icon on google translate, then changed to chrome and there it is. Neverthelss I can't find the way to make punctuations signs work in spanish, so I turned to VoiceIn (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-in-voice-typing/pjnefijmagpdjfhhkpljicbbpicelgko/related?hl=en) and DeepL

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record I'll post the solution I found so far:

- Add the [Voice In Voice Typing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-in-voice-typing/pjnefijmagpdjfhhkpljicbbpicelgko/related?hl=en) extension to Chrome
- Goto to [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) online translator

that's it

> I couldn't find a way to make [punctuation marks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-punctuation) work with google translate, so I switched to VoiceIn that works great with [punctuation marks](https://dictanote.co/voicein/voicecommands/es/)